# How to start a particular Android activity first

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm making an Android app, and I want to know how to create a specific activity on the start of the program. I understand the "intent" code, but I want to know how to start a specific activity on the *start* of the app other than the one that automatically starts. How do I do this? Do I have to implement more "intent" code? Is this on the Android documentation?

Comment: Please read the documentation for the manifest.  Just add an intent filter for the launcher.

Comment: `and a fast answer would be much appreciated.` reading the documentation and/or a Google search would have been significantly faster than posting a question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare an Activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` declare an `intent-filter` like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.your.package"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
<application
            ...>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_Name"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

The action of this intent-filter is used to determine which is the starting Activity for your application.

From the **[docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)**:

The `ACTION_MAIN` action indicates this is the main entry point and does not expect any intent data.

The `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` category indicates that this activity's icon should be placed in the system's app launcher. If the  element does not specify an icon with icon, then the system uses the icon from the  element.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo  I disagree.  On some versions of Android, that can cause weird runtime errors.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo you can use both!

Comment: Yes, you can. I just said "better". But then Simon disagreed. And since he's more expert than me, I removed my comment. I also upvoted your answer, so...